# Scanning ProgressIndicatorUI cannot see Cancel button

Tags: c#, twain

I have an application which uses Twain driver to scan documents to preview on my application. When I am scanning the documents, it should show a Progress Indicator of the process of scanning the document. And right there, there is a cancel button if I wish to cancel the scan in mid process. However, there the `"Cancel"` text is not visible but the button is and I would like to make it visible but I am not sure about it.

Below is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image: Screenshot]

My code settings:

```
var settings = new ScanSettings
    {
        UseDocumentFeeder = ADF,
        ShowTwainUI = EnableUI,
        ShowProgressIndicatorUI = true,              
        UseDuplex = EnableDuplex,
        Resolution = rs,
        Page = pg
    };

    try
    {
        TwainHandler.StartScanning(settings);
    }
    catch (TwainException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //Enabled = true;
        //BringToFront();
    }
}
```

I could only figure how to hide or enable the Progress Indicator as a whole but I can't make the cancel text show up.

Does anyone know what do I need to do?

Comment: I think button is visible but its text is not, you may change properties of cancel button from property windows

Comment: Yes the text is not visible but button is

Comment: Property windows? This progress indicator is enabled through 'ShowProgressIndicatorUI' as true and it's not created in any property windows so the button is added by default